# Stage.enter doesn't start the wizard

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf

I created an application which display a survey wizard to the user. When the user launch the /start command, I call the `AddProject`:

```
const Telegraf = require('telegraf');
const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
const session = require('telegraf/session');
bot.use(session());

const main = new TelegrafInlineMenu("Welcome.");
main.setCommand('start');
main.simpleButton('Start Survey', 'START_SURVEY', {
  doFunc: async ctx => surveyController.AddProject(ctx, bot)
});
```

essentially the code above create a menu that display the label Welcome and a button to start the survey. When the user click on the button, the method AddProject is called from the surveyController:

```
const Composer = require('telegraf/composer');
const stepHandler = new Composer();
const Stage = require('telegraf/stage');
const WizardScene = require('telegraf/scenes/wizard');
const userController = require('../controllers/user.controller');

module.exports = {

  AddProject: async function (ctx, bot) {

    const superWizard = new WizardScene('super-wizard',
      (ctx) => {
        ctx.reply('Step 1', Markup.inlineKeyboard([
          Markup.urlButton('❤️', 'http://telegraf.js.org'),
          Markup.callbackButton('➡️ Next', 'next'),
        ]).extra());
        return ctx.wizard.next();
      },
      (ctx) => {
        ctx.reply('Step 2');
        return ctx.wizard.next();
      },
      (ctx) => {
        ctx.reply('Done');
        return ctx.wizard.leave();
      },
    );

    const stage = new Stage([superWizard]);
    bot.use(stage.middleware());
    Stage.enter('super-wizard');
  },
};
```

the method AddProject is firing correctly, but the wizard is not displayed, what I did wrong?

Comment: I went through your code, a `js snipped` would help troubleshoot this question, plus could you point me to the docs pages relative to this functionalities inside https://telegraf.js.org/#/?id=telegraf

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio I fixed my problem, I added an answer below, hope this will help other users, thanks anyway for your help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After a lot of attempts I finally achieved my goal. I'm not an expert of `TelegrafJS` and I found the documentation really hard to understand, specially if you are a newbie (missing examples, some concept like WizardScene missing etc...).

**Create a Scene**

So basically to achieve my target I have to use a `Scene` and `TelegrafJS` makes available different types of `Scene`s.

My goal was to wait for user input, and validate it. For this, I have used the `WizardScene`, this is my implementation:

```
const userWizard = new WizardScene('user-wizard',
    (ctx) => {
        ctx.reply("What is your name?");

        //Necessary for store the input
        ctx.scene.session.user = {};

        //Store the telegram user id
        ctx.scene.session.user.userId = ctx.update.callback_query.from.id;
        return ctx.wizard.next();
    },
    (ctx) => {

        //Validate the name
        if (ctx.message.text.length < 1 || ctx.message.text.length > 12) {
            return ctx.reply("Name entered has an invalid length!");
        }

        //Store the entered name
        ctx.scene.session.user.name = ctx.message.text;
        ctx.reply("What is your last name?");
        return ctx.wizard.next();
    },
    async (ctx) => {

        //Validate last name
        if (ctx.message.text.length > 30) {
            return ctx.reply("Last name has an invalid length");
        }

        ctx.scene.session.user.lastName = ctx.message.text;

        //Store the user in a separate controller
        await userController.StoreUser(ctx.scene.session.user);
        return ctx.scene.leave(); //<- Leaving a scene will clear the session automatically
    }
);
```

**Register a Scene**

the `WizardScene` above need to be registered in a `Stage`, so we can use this `Scene` in a `Middleware`. In this way, we can access to the `Scene` in a separate class or module:

```
const stage = new Stage([userWizard]);
stage.command('cancel', (ctx) => {
    ctx.reply("Operation canceled");
    return ctx.scene.leave();
});
bot.use(stage.middleware())
```

I also told to the `Stage` to leave the `Scene` if the `/cancel` command is reiceved, so if the user want cancel the operation, typing `/cancel` is the way.

**Start a Scene**

Now for enter in the wizard you can do the following:

```
await ctx.scene.enter('user-wizard');
```

so basically you have the `Scene` middleware registered in the `context` of your application, and you need to type `.enter` with the id of your `Scene` which is in my case `user-wizard`.

This will start the wizard.

I hope the documentation will be enhanced with more example, because I found this really hard to implement and understand, specially for me that I'm a newbie on `TelegrafJS`.

Kind regards.